# Why does std::operator>>(istream&, char&) extract whitespace?

Tags: c++

I was compiling the following program and I learned that the extractor for a `char&` proceeds to extract a character even if it is a whitespace character. I disabled the skipping of leading whitespace characters expecting the proceeding read attempts to fail (because formatted extraction stops at whitespace), but was surprised when it succeeded.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("a b c");
    char a, b, c;

    iss >> std::noskipws;

    if (iss >> a >> b >> c)
    { 
        std::cout <<     "a = \"" << a
                  << "\"\nb = \"" << b
                  << "\"\nc = \"" << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> a = "a"
> b = " "
> c = "b"
> ```

As you can see from the output, `b` was given the value of the space between `"a"` and `"b"`; and `c` was given the following character `"b"`. I was expecting both `b` and `c` to not have a value at all since the extraction should fail because of the leading whitespace. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/

Comment: According to the resource, it ignores white space (not fails) until a non white space character is in place. EDIT: you are using noskipws which stands for "don't skip whitespace" which gives you an expected result.

Comment: Check out the example (also sorry about 3 comments In a row. It sucks to write from a phone): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/

Comment: I don't understand the question; you explicitly asked the stream to *not skip whitespace*, so why is the behavior surprising?

Comment: @Gasim and @Praetorian : Whitespace is a delimiter for input. The extraction was expected to fail because normally the extractors for other types (such as `std::string`, `int` and other numeric types) all stop at whitespace *even if* `std::noskipws` is turned on. I've seen this question asked a couple times before so I was just trying to clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

In IOStreams, characters have virtually no formatting requirements. Any and all characters in the character sequence are valid candidates for an extraction. For the extractors that use the numeric facets, extraction is defined to stop at whitespace. However, the extractor for `charT&` works directly on the buffer, indiscriminately returning the next available character presumably by a call to `rdbuf()->sbumpc()`.

Do not assume that this behavior extends to the extractor for pointers to characters as for them extraction is explicitly defined to stop at whitespace.