# How does char extraction differ from string extraction?

Tags: c++

When disabling whitespace skipping with chars and strings the behavior is different. It seems the only way to extract an entire string (including whitespace characters) is to use chars and noskipws. But this is not possible with strings because it won't extract after the first space.

```
std::string test = "a b c";
char c;
std::istringstream iss(test);
iss.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
while (iss >> c)
    std::cout << c;
```

will output `a b c` but change c to string and it only outputs `a`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820867/why-does-stdoperatoristream-char-extract-whitespace

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator for a string extracts words, and stops at the
first white space it sees.  If it doesn't skip initial white
space, then it stops immediately, and returns an empty string.

You don't say how you want the string to be delimited.  To read
until the end of line, just use `std::getline`.  To read until
the end of file, you can use something like:

```
std::istringstream collector;
collector << iss.rdbuf();
std::string results = collector.str();
```

It's not the most efficient, but if the file is small, it will
do.